Heavy rock band/little girl knocks own hat off..
My mom and I are trying to figure out what movie this is from: the trailer starts with a heavy rock band and another part of the trailer shows a guy and a girl sitting on a bench and when the guy tries to brush the girls hair out of her face she knocks her hat off. Also my mom remembers someone having a name that sounds like bug and a heavy guy with really curly hair. PLEASE HELP (And if it helps: my mom says the girl on the bench reminds her of Demi Lovato but I checked her list of movies and we couldn't find this one)

May it be "The Rocker" (2008). It is a comedy about a Rock band. 

Also my mom remembers someone having a name that sounds like bug 

The main character is nicknamed "Fish"

and a heavy guy with really curly hair.

One of the protagonists fits that description 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1031969/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_22

The Rocker tells the story of a failed drummer who is given a second chance at fame. Robert "Fish" Fishman is the extremely dedicated and astoundingly passionate drummer for the eighties hair band Vesuvius, who is living the rock n' roll dream until he is unceremoniously kicked out of the band. Twenty years after his rock star fantasies are destroyed, just when Fish has finally given up all hope, he hears that his nephew's high school rock band A.D.D. is looking for a new drummer. They reluctantly make him the newest member of the band, giving him a chance to reclaim the rock God throne he's always thought he deserved, and taking the young band along for the ride of their lives. 

